# How to cancel all methods in DoWork while clicking cancel button?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I know this is not the first question about cancelling a `BackGroundWorker` but I didn't find the answer to solve my problem.

If I click the `cancel` (abort) button in alertbox I need to terminate all methods in `Dowork` method. Here `Queryexecution` and `settingForControl` methods are another class methods. If I give the abort option at any time it will need to terminate all methods.

How to achieve this?

My current code is:

```
CancelSupportedBackgroundWorker backGroundWorker = new CancelSupportedBackgroundWorker {
    WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
};

AlertBox alertBox = new AlertBox
{
    WaitingText = "Loading",
    WaitingHeaderText = "Loading Indicator",
};
alertBox.IsBusy = true;
alertBox.AbortButton.Click += (obj, arg) =>
{
    backGroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    alertBox.AbortButton.IsEnabled = false;
    backGroundWorker.Abort();
    backGroundWorker.Dispose();
};
backGroundWorker.DoWork += (obj, arg) =>
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(
        delegate ()
        {
            try
            {
                query.SettingForControl();
                query.QueryExecution(connectionstring);
                alertBox.AbortButton.IsEnabled = false;

                if (backGroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                    arg.Cancel = true;
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    alertBox.IsBusy = false;
                }, 
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                arg.Cancel = true;
            }   
        })
    );
};
backGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, arg) =>
{
    if (arg.Cancelled)
    {
        alertBox.IsBusy = false;
        return;
    }
    alertBox.IsBusy = false;    
};
backGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(this);
```

Comment: Why do you combine BackgroundWorker and Dispatcher.Invoke? One of the two mechanisms should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official way is to use a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx). You would create an instance of `CancellationTokenSource` in `AlertBox`, then pass the `Token` from the source to the `BackgroundWorker`.

The `BackgroundWorker` would then pass the Token to all the methods it calls.

You have to modify all the methods involved to receive a `CancellationToken` as a parameter and check for the cancellation state of the token regularly by calling its `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` method. Also check for the state of the token in the `DoWork` handler itself.

You can then cancel the action by calling the `Cancel`method on the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.it will be helpful to solve.But how to set isCancellationRequested property to true of token and when to set that @NineBerry

Comment: @Pandi When you call `Cancel()`on the `CancellationTokenSource`, the property is set to true on its tokens.